# Derivation of $\nabla \times \textbf{u}$ in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cross-product, curl

Here is an attempt to derive the curl in cylindrical coordinates

\begin{align*}
 \omega =\text{Curl }\vec{V}(x,y,z) &= 
 \nabla \times \textbf{u} =\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\[0.3cm]
  \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\\[0.3cm]
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix}
 \times
 \begin{bmatrix}
  u_r \\
  u_{\phi} \\
  u_z
 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\[0.3cm]
  \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\\[0.3cm]
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix}
 \times
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  u_{\phi} \\
  0
 \end{bmatrix} \\
 &= 
 \det \begin{pmatrix}
  \hat{\imath} & \hat{\jmath} & \hat{k} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{\partial}{\partial r} & \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  u_r & u_{\phi} & u_z
 \end{pmatrix}\\
 &= \hat{\imath}\big(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial u_{\phi}} - \frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial z}\big)
 -
 \hat{\jmath}\big(\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z}\big)
 +
 \hat{k}\big(\frac{\partial u_{\phi}}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \phi}\big) \\
 &= \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial u_{\phi}} - \frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{\partial u_{\phi}}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \phi}
 \end{bmatrix}\qquad \textbf{(1)}\\
 &= \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial u_{\phi}} - \frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{1}{r}\big(
  \frac{\partial r u_{\phi}}{\partial r} -\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \phi}\big)
 \end{bmatrix} \qquad \textbf{(2)}\\
\end{align*}

This corresponds, I think to the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates), with the appropriate screenshot:

[image: pic from wikipedia]

**Here is my question**:

Going from **(1)** to **(2)** how can we mathematically assert/prove that $\frac{\partial u_{\phi}}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial r u_{\phi}}{\partial r}$

Comment: I don't think that is true. Is your question how to derive the curl in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @nicoguaro. Yes that's my question. I added a picture and a link to wikipedia. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let us start from the [components written in curvilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Definition)

\begin{align}
& (\operatorname{curl}\mathbf F)_1=\frac{1}{h_2h_3}\left (\frac{\partial (h_3F_3)}{\partial u_2}-\frac{\partial (h_2F_2)}{\partial u_3}\right ), \\[5pt]
& (\operatorname{curl}\mathbf F)_2=\frac{1}{h_3h_1}\left (\frac{\partial (h_1F_1)}{\partial u_3}-\frac{\partial (h_3F_3)}{\partial u_1}\right ), \\[5pt]
& (\operatorname{curl}\mathbf F)_3=\frac{1}{h_1h_2}\left (\frac{\partial (h_2F_2)}{\partial u_1}-\frac{\partial (h_1F_1)}{\partial u_2}\right ).
\end{align}

In this case $(u_1, u_2, u_3) = (\rho, \phi, z)$, and $h_1 = 1$, $h_2 = \rho$, $h_3 = 1$.

Writing the curl as $\nabla\times \mathbf{F}$ is confusing to me because the cross product is more complicated in other coordinates than Cartesian, and it is not the definition but a notation of it. The same goes to the matrix form, if you want to write it in that way it would be:

$$\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{F} =
\begin{vmatrix}
h_1 \hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 &h_2 \hat{\mathbf{e}}_2 &h_3 \hat{\mathbf{e}}_3\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial u_1} & \frac{\partial}{\partial u_2} & \frac{\partial}{\partial u_3}\\
h_1 F_1 & h_2 F_2 & h_3 F_3
\end{vmatrix}\, .$$

Comment: Many thanks, for your answer @nicoguaro. That helps to understand the result a bit. However what do $F_x$ and $h_x$ represent exactly. Would it be possible to rewrite the initial state: $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\
  \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}
  u_r \\
  u_{\phi} \\
  u_z
 \end{bmatrix}$: with the $F_x$ and $n_x$ notation?

Comment: @ecjb, $F_x$ is the component of $\mathbf{F}$ in the $x$ coordinate and $h_x$ is the scale factor associated to that coordinate, for Cartesian $h_x = h_y = h_z = 1$. Regarding writing it in that way ... I think that is possible but you need to consider the derivatives of the unit vectors.